# $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A \cap[-n, n] = A \cap \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [-n, n] $?

Tags: measure-theory

If I have $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A\cap[-n,n]$, is it allowed to extract $A$ such that $A\cap\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-n,n]$?  $A$ is in the Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Great, then my proof works. @TheSilverDoe Btw, what is $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-n, n]$ ?  Can I assume that it is $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-n, n]=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: never mind, got it

Comment: Yes, $\cup [-n,n] = \mathbb{R}$.